# Create simple Timer in ReactJS ( not using useEffect )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I'm making and app where if a person encounters a problem he has a chance to request help by pressing a button. After a minute or two his problem is resolved.

I need to record how long that time was.
I could do it using useEffect + setInterval where every 1000 ms I increase the variable by 1 however this would cause issues if while waiting user changes the browser tab ( browser will reduce re-renders and time is not recorded correctly )

Can you suggest a good easy wait to record waiting time in React?

E.g. I'm thinking of a code that stores time when button is pressed and then every second the component shows current time - recorded time.

Thanks

Comment: After pressing the help button, does the user have to wait for one or two minute idle in the screen? What does the screen become?

Well, in over to make it compatible across the browser, you could setup a cookie and listen to that cookie. And record the time accordingly with respect to that cookie. Works across the browser tab too.

Comment: you can save the timestamp of the first click and the timestamp of second event and submit the difference. `end - start`

Comment: After pressing the button  , the user just waits - potentially the clock showing how much he is waiting would show up. For the end - start solution can you help me with the code? I've never used datetime functions in react before.

Comment: @PeterSlanina let's see some code. What have you tried? And your need reds exactly like useEffect + setInterval.